# php cgi on android unrooted

Tags: php, android, cgi

I want to install php cgi on android.  I have put the CGI PHP binaries in the data folder but this will not work unless I set permissions to 755 on the binaries. I think they also have to be executable.  Is there a way that this can be done on an installation on an unrooted device?

I have seen something similar on PAW server. I would prefer this to happen on the SD card if possible. I am completely lost at acheiving this and really need this for an app. I have already used php for android and I didn't  realize that this was just the cli version.

Comment: i use droidphp and it works fine on unrooted phones.

Answer (score 1):

For the /sdcard, there is no way to do this on an unrooted device. In every case I've seen the SDCARD is vfat formatted, meaning chmod 755 doesn't mean anything because vfat doesn't support user permissions. Aside from this, I'm pretty sure android is coded not to execute from the /sdcard anyways.

Your only chance is to run it in application space. Copy the binaries into your android assets folder, the programtically run "chmod 755 /data/data//mybinfile" and try executing it via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. I've done this will shell scripts before and it works, I don't know if it will work on binaries though. But I'm pretty sure, unrooted, that this is your only option.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. The file I have tested works in any directory as long as 755 permissions. I just tried the sdcard and obviously it wont give me these permissions. Is this something I could compile into an APK, without getting the user to root the phone. Sorry I am new to java.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, that is impossible. You need ownership of the files or you need to be root to do the `chmod`, and I believe you don't either with the default user apps run as.

Answer (score 0):

Android blocks the execution of binarys from the sdcard by default. You can include them in an App and run them with

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( some list here with the args );`

`Process p = pb.start();`

Then using the Process object you can even get the Applications output.